# How do I check if the board in tic tac toe doesn't have a number any more

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

for a school assignment I need to make tic tac toe, I've got pretty much everything ready, except for 1 issue, I don't know how to make the game know when it's a draw and then quit

in the function check_tie()
you can still see I have some attempts left over.

The spots in the tic tac toe board have to be numbers from 1-9 so I can't replace them with empty spaces. Meaning I can't do a check to see if there are no empty spots left

thanks in advance

Here's the full code

```
    print ("*** Welcome to Tic Tac Teen ***")


gameboard = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

game_running = True
winner = None
player = 'X'

marker = ['X', 'O']

player_list = []
name1 = input("Fill in the name of player 1: ")
player_list.append(name1)

name2 = input("Fill in the name of player 2: ")
player_list.append(name2)


print("These are the players:", player_list)
print("These are their markers:", marker)

# Function to print gameboard
def print_gameboard(gameboard):
    print("  -----------")
    print(" | " + gameboard[0] + " | " + gameboard[1] + " | " + gameboard[2] + " | ")
    print("  -----------")
    print(" | " + gameboard[3] + " | " + gameboard[4] + " | " + gameboard[5] + " | ")
    print("  -----------")
    print(" | " + gameboard[6] + " | " + gameboard[7] + " | " + gameboard[8] + " | ")
    print("  -----------")

print()


#Checks if the game is over by checking for a win or tie:
def check_if_game_over():
    check_win()
    check_tie()

def check_win():
    global winner
    winner_row = check_row()
    winner_column = check_column()
    winner_diagonal = check_diagonal()

    #Gets the winer
    if winner_row:
        winner = winner_row
    elif winner_column:
        winner = winner_column
    elif winner_diagonal:
        winner = winner_diagonal
    else: winner = None # / Tie?

#checks rows for a win, by comparing if the elements in the row are the same
def check_row():
    global game_running
    row1 = gameboard[0] == gameboard[1] == gameboard[2] 
    row2 = gameboard[3] == gameboard[4] == gameboard[5] 
    row3 = gameboard[6] == gameboard[7] == gameboard[8] 

    if row1 or row2 or row3:
        game_running = False
    if row1:
        return gameboard[0]
    elif row2:
        return gameboard[3]
    elif row3:
        return gameboard[6]

def check_column():
    global game_running
    column1 = gameboard[0] == gameboard[3] == gameboard[6] 
    column2 = gameboard[1] == gameboard[4] == gameboard[7] 
    column3 = gameboard[2] == gameboard[5] == gameboard[8] 

    if column1 or column2 or column3:
        game_running = False
    if column1:
        return gameboard[0]
    elif column2:
        return gameboard[1]
    elif column3:
        return gameboard[2]

def check_diagonal():
    global game_running
    diag1 = gameboard[0] == gameboard[4] == gameboard[8] 
    diag2 = gameboard[2] == gameboard[4] == gameboard[6] 

    if diag1 or diag2:
        game_running = False
    if diag1:
        return gameboard[0]
    elif diag2:
        return gameboard[2]


def check_tie():
    return
    global game_running
    if not position.isdigit():
        game_running = False

    # global game_running
    # if moves == 9:
    #     game_running = False
        

def switch_player():
    global player

    #Switches player depending on who's turn it is.
    if player =="X":
        player = "O"
    elif player == "O":
        player = "X"

    #function that runs the whole game
def play_game():

    while game_running:

        print("This is the current gameboard:")
        moves = 0
        print_gameboard(gameboard)
        
        player_turn(player)

        check_if_game_over()

        switch_player()
    
    if winner == "X":
        print(player_list[0] + " won!")
    elif winner == "O":
        print(player_list[1] + " won!" )
    elif winner == None:
        print("It's a tie!")

    
def player_turn(player):
    position = input("Choose a spot from 1-9: ")
    

    while position not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
        position = input("That's not a number between 1-9, try again: ")

    position = int(position) - 1

    # if gameboard[position] = taken (how do you do this?, )
        #print(Position is already taken, please pick another spot)
    gameboard[position] = player
    print_gameboard(gameboard)

play_game()
```

Comment: Since a move replaces a number (1-9) with ""X" or "O" on the gameboard, couldn't you check if there are any numbers left on the gameboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works okay as is, just replace the `check_tie()` function with this

```
def check_tie():
    global game_running
    game_running = any(tile.isdigit() for tile in gameboard)
```

You had the right idea, just didn't loop through the tiles.

For clarity, `any()` is a function that returns `True` if one of the evaluated values is `True`. Otherwise returns `False`. `isdigit()` is a method belonging to `string` which checks if all the characters included are digits or not.

Comment: hey I had a question, because this now breaks the code in a different way, adding this code makes it so the game doesn't end until 9 tiles are filled, in other words, when there is a winner the game doesn't end for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Well the only way it can be a draw is when there is no winner after 9 moves right? After 9 moves just check if there is a winner; if there still isnt then it is a draw.

So in play_game() i would loop for 9 times, in each loop I would show the board like you did, make the move, check for winner, if winner then return, if not keep looping. If I happen to exit out of the loop then that means I've used up all of my moves and that there is no winner so it must be a tie.

Edit: Thats just how I would approach the problem. Your method works just as well. There is no right or wrong answer

Comment: I also think this solution is less error prone and fits the game logic.